# What is the difference between "schätzen" and "abschätzen"?

Tags: word-choice

The following to sentenses have different meanings

```
Er schätzt sie.        

Er schätzt sie ab.
```

But looking at

```
Er schätzt die zurückgelegte Strecke auf 5 Kilometer.
```

and

```
Er schätzt, dass er zur Lösung der Aufgabe ca. 3 Tage braucht.
```

it seems, that **schätzen** is used in the sense of **abschätzen**, without using the **ab** explicitly.

I admit, the more I think about it, the more I get confused.

Sorry I can't translate the example sentences. Just started arguing with my online translators, which seem as confused as I'm.

Are here some rules to understand the proper usage?

Answer (score 6):

*Schätzen* can mean *estimate* and be equal to *abschätzen* as you noted. It can also mean to regard higly, like, cherish, admire, etc.

Your first sentence translates to

> He regards her highly

The second sentence translates to

> He is evaluating her/ [sizing her up](http://www.dict.cc/deutsch-englisch/absch%C3%A4tzen.html)

The only way to differentiate between the two meanings of *schätzen* is through context. For example:

> Der Läufer schätzt die Strecke.

This could mean that the runner likes the track, or that he estimates the distance. Without further context, this sentence is not translatable with certainty.

Answer (score 0):

> Er schätzt sie.

Ist die verkürzte Form für 'wertschätzen'. Jemanden wertschätzen bedeutet in erster Linie achten, respektieren aber oft auch mögen.

> Er schätzt sie ab.

dagegen bedeutet taxieren, also erst herausfinden, ob sie einen Wert hat oder worin dieser bestehen könnte.

> Wir schätzen ihre Haarlänge auf 90 Zentimeter.

Hier gibt es kein "ab", weil wir eine konkrete Schätzung haben - wir haben das Ergebnis der Abschätzung.

> Wir schätzen ihre Haarlänge ab, sobald sie uns den Rücken kehrt.

Da wäre wieder ein "ab" gefragt.

> Wir schätzen ihre Haarlänge.

Da wäre wieder Wertschätzung gemeint, nachdem wir wissen, wie lange die Haare sind.

Comment: "Schätz mal, wie lang meine Haar sind" - Ich habe noch nie die Aufforderung zum *Abschätzen* mit *ab* gehört. Dies steht in Kontrast zu deiner Aussage. Demnach müsst es nämlich heißen: "Schätze mal ab, wie lang meine Haare sind."