# Which is correct, "geschätzte Stunden" or "abgeschätzte Stunden"?

Tags: word-choice

I want to ask someone what the "estimated hours" are for a project.

Which is correct:

> Was sind die **geschätzten** Stunden für dieses Projekt? / Wie viel Stunden würdest du **schätzen**?
>
> Was sind die **abgeschätzten** Stunden für dieses Projekt? / Wie viel Stunden würdest du **abschätzen**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grammatically, both versions are correct (IMHO). There's almost no semantic difference between them.

As a very slight difference, with "abschätzen" i would expect an acting person, *someone who estimates*. "geschätzt" denotes the result, saying that the result isn't determined exactly but just estimated.

Because of that, for the first sentences, („Was sind die...“), i would prefer "schätzen / geschätzt", because they don't tell *who estimated* the time required. For the second versions (the question: „Wie viel(e) Stunden...“), IMHO both versions are equivalent.

In general, "abschätzen" has the advantage to avoid confusion because of the ambiguity of "schätzen" (see [Hackworth's reply on the difference between "schätzen" and "abschätzen"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2792/what-is-the-difference-between-schatzen-and-abschatzen/2794#2794)).

Comment: Was sind die Höchst-Km/h in dieser Kurve?

Answer (score 2):

A clue on what to use preferably may give you the answer to the question when you ask:

> **Question:** *"Was schätzen Sie, wie viele Stunden das Projekt benötigt?"*
>
> **Answer:** *"[Ich schätze,] wir brauchen ungefähr 10 bis 12 Stunden"*

This is when you ask for a rough estimate of the time needed for the project. In both cases "*abschätzen"* is wrong and can not be used.

In another variant you may ask:

> **Question:** *"Können Sie schon abschätzen, wie lange Sie brauchen?"*
>
> **Answer:** *"[Ich schätze,] wir brauchen noch 10 bis 12 Stunden"*

This is when asking for a more precise estimate of the time needed. This variant is used less frequently. In this case you can answer the question the same way but still you can not use *"abschätzen"*.

In both answers "*schätzen"* can be omitted but it may be more expected when you do so in the second case.

In most cases "*schätzen*" is to be used preferably. This helps to avoid errors from using "*abschätzen*" in the wrong place, e.g. when building an adjective

> *"In geschätzten 3 Stunden sind wir fertig."*

This is correct - *"abgeschätzt"* can not be used here.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with tohuwabohu that probably both are 'correct'. In terms of usage, however, I'd definitely prefer "schätzen".

In my experience, "abschätzen" is mostly used in questions like

> "Kannst Du schon abschätzen wie lange es noch dauert?"

i.e. following the pattern: "können" + "addressee" + "abschätzen" + "amount or similar speaker is asking about".

At least that's how it seems to me in southern Germany.

(The abiguity of "schätzen" only *very* rarely is an issue, since the context makes it very clear in most cases which of the two meanings is intended. Also, "schätzen" in the sense of "esteem" is rather formal.)

Answer (score 0):

Alle vier Sätze sind krumm und falsch:

> Was sind die geschätzten Stunden für dieses Projekt? / Wie viel Stunden würdest du schätzen?
>
> Was sind die abgeschätzten Stunden für dieses Projekt? / Wie viel Stunden würdest du abschätzen?

Bessere Formulierungen:

- Was ist die geschätzte Dauer des Projekts?
- Auf wieviele Stunden würdest Du dieses Projekt schätzen?
- Was schätzt Du, wieviele Stunden wir an diesem Projekt arbeiten?

Der bestimmte Artikel "die Stunden" scheint mir falsch, weil es um unbestimmte Stunden geht. Die Stunden sind die Maßeinheit, und gefragt ist in Wahrheit die Dauer. Die Antwort auf die ersten Versionen der Fragen wären sonst "Die Stunde von montags, 8-9, die Stunden von 11-14 Uhr, und Mittwochs von 17-18 Uhr." - das wären die geschätzten Stunden, mit bestimmtem Artikel.

Und zur Frageform 2:

> "Wie viel Stunden würdest du schätzen?"
> "Oh, zum schätzen würde ich allenfalls 20 Sekunden benötigen!"

Diese Form wird durchaus benutzt, aber ohne Kontext kann der Satz m.E. nicht so stehenbleiben.

"Ich denke wir brauchen 4 Tage für das Projekt. Wie viel Stunden würdest du schätzen?" - dann geht's.

Comment: -1, da grammatikalisch falsch. Der bestimmte Artikel ist korrekt; das Nomen ist durch „für das Projekt“ bestimmt. „Was ist die geschätzte Dauer für das Projekt?“ - auch hier ist die Dauer inhaltlich unbestimmt, grammatikalisch aber bestimmt. Man könnte eher „Stunden“ durch „Stundenzahl“ ersetzen. Das ist aber eine Frage der Wortwahl bzw des Stils, nicht der Grammatik. Die Verbesserungen helfen übrigens nicht: wenn man die Frage partout missverstehen will, kann man auf die letzte Version ebenfalls mit „für die Schätzung...“ antworten. Also: alles vier richtig, aber in der Wortwahl variierbar.

Comment: Gut, meine Erklärung ist falsch, aber die Sätze sind es auch. Die Antwort auf Frage 1 würde doch lauten "Was sind die Stunden ...?" - "Die Stunden sind eine Zeiteinheit." Das Fragewort muß "Wieviele ..." lauten.

Comment: Nein. Mit „was ist“ können ziemlich viele Fragen eingeleitet werden: „Was ist der Betrag / was ist die Summe / was ist die Dauer...“ etc., und es wird jeweils keine Definition von Betrag, Summe oder Dauer erwartet, sondern eine Bezifferung. Also sollte man erstens den Schwerpunkt der Frage erfassen, und das waren hier die Verben. Und dann sollte man es den Leuten nicht unnötig schwer machen, indem man Stilfragen als Grammatikfragen auffasst. Ich bleibe dabei: Selbstverständlich **kann** man ein präziseres Fragewort wählen, aber man **muss** es nicht.

Comment: Wir wollen aber niemandem schlechtes Deutsch beibringen. Ein Satz, der irgendwie verstanden wird, ist noch lange nicht richtig, geschweige denn gut. Die Beispiele mit `Betrag` und `Summe` sind unsachgemäß, und wären richtig, wenn die Frage lautete, `Was ist die geschätzte Dauer des Projekts`. Ich werde es in meine Antwort übernehmen.