# Difference between "einschätzen" and "abschätzen"?

Tags: difference, word-choice

What is the difference in usage between *einschätzen* and *abschätzen*?

In the online "Pons" dictionary, they both mean *to assess*, *to estimate* with the addition of *to judge* for *einschätzen*, which doesn't help differentiate much.

In which different situations would they be used?

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between “schätzen” and “abschätzen”?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/2792/9551)

Comment: "abschätzen" implies *approximating a value* on a given scale. "einschätzen" implies *classifying an entity* into a category. You would use the former for predicting how long something will take, but the latter to assess whether zou want to be someone's friend.

Answer (score 10):

*Einschätzen* is used when you are evaluating something, e.g.:

> die Situation einschätzen = judge/assess the situation

*Abschätzen*, on the other hand, is used when you are trying to estimate something, e.g.:

> die Anzahl der Sterne abschätzen = estimate the quantity of stars

So, *einschätzen* is used as *to assess* or *to judge* and *abschätzen* as estimate.

Comment: Hello and welcome! Up vote for the good examples! I think "assess" and "appraise", which you used in your translation are better than "evaluate".

Comment: Hello and thanks for the warm welcome ;) true you could be right .. also thanks for the edit!

Comment: There are cases, though, where you can use "abschätzen" instead of "einschätzen". For instance, everyone would understand "Kannst Du schon abschätzen, wann Du kommst?". I can't think of an example for using "einschätzen" instead of "abschätzen" though.